Is a finite lattice determined by its Hasse diagram (as a graph)?
If finite lattices $L_1,L_2$ have Hasse diagrams that are isomorphic as undirected graphs, must $L_1$ and $L_2$ be isomorphic?
NOTE: Sam Hopkins points out that the answer is “no” because there are lattices that are not isomorphic to their duals. I would like to know if this “which way is up?” ambiguity is the only obstacle to reconstructing a lattice from its Hasse diagram (viewed as an undirected graph).

What do you mean by "graph"? The undirected graph? Then surely not, since there are finite lattices that are not self-dual (but the Hasse diagrams of dual lattices would be isomorphic as undirected graphs).

On the other hand if by "graph" you mean "directed graph" then the Hasse diagram is the same information as the cover relation of the partial order, and then it is a simple fact that for a finite partial order it is the transitive, reflexive closure of its cover relation; hence this digraph does determine the finite poset (the lattice property is irrelevant here).

Good point! Let me rephrase the question: can we reconstruct a lattice from its Hasse diagram as an undirected graph, up to duality?

How much information beyond just the undirected graph is enough?

@MichaelHardy well, as I said, if you know the directed graph, that is enough to recover the poset (and the lattice property is irrelevant). I suppose you could ask, how many of the edge directions do you need to know.

@SamHopkins : Exactly. I expect in some cases one is enough.

@MichaelHardy well I would expect in "most" cases, none is enough (a "generic" poset/lattice should be determined by its Hasse diagram, up to duality).

If you have one such arrow, then you don't need to say "up to duality." So that one should be enough if you're right.

This is still far from true. Consider for example these lattices (just a random example):


Also the cycle graph $C_{2n+2}$ is the Hasse diagram of $n$ nonisomorphic lattices.

Instead of a "random" example, is there such a thing as a simplest example?

So how much information beyond just the undirected graph is enough?

@MichaelHardy I don't think there is any example with 5 elements, and so 6 elements is minimal (though as bof explained, there is at least one other example with 6 elements).

In comments it was guessed that in most cases the undirected graph would be enough, up to duality.  Here is some data from small instances. The lattices were taken from Gebhardt and Tawn's catalogue, and simple Sage code was used to classify the lattices by the undirected graph.
The columns of the table are:

n: number of elements
lattices: number of nonisomorphic lattices of n elements up to duality (A373922)
graphs: number of different undirected graphs as their Hasse diagrams
uniques: number of graphs that correspond to one lattice only (up to duality)
%: uniques/lattices




n
lattices
graphs
uniques
%




4
2
2
2
100.0


5
4
4
4
100.0


6
11
9
7
63.6


7
33
23
16
48.5


8
129
76
47
36.3


9
577
285
153
26.5


10
3113
1346
646
20.8


11
19092
7403
3306
17.3


12
132318
47919
20591
15.6



From this small data it would seem, contrary to what was guessed, that most lattices are not identifiable from the undirected Hasse diagram (even up to duality).
At $n=12$, the following graph corresponds to the largest number of lattices (48, not counting duals).

But graphs that have very many lattices (like 48) are not typical. Much more typical is that a graph corresponds to e.g. 2 different lattices (11761 such graphs of 12 vertices) or 3 lattices (5492 graphs of 12 vertices). Here is a randomly chosen example of a graph that corresponds to exactly two different lattices (disregarding duals).
 
